# How do I get EXM 3.5 databases on SQL 2014?

Tags: exm

I'm trying to setup EXM 3.5 on my Sitecore 8.2u5 instance, which uses a SQL 2014 server. The databases that EXM 3.5 delivers and according to its installation guide you have to attach, seem to be made with SQL 2016, and therefore cannot be attached to a SQL 2014 instance. 
Anyone knows of a work around? Or is SQL 2014 just not supported for EXM 3.5?

Comment: I looked at the prerequisites for Sitecore 8.2u5, and I can see there a required databases are SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2012. It means the databases of EXM should also be compatible with them due the EXM 3.5 works just with Sitecore 8.2u5. Have you got any errors during attaching databases?

Comment: Is ExM 3.5 is distributed with ExM database? Previously(up to 3.2) it was distributed with SQL script (either in data folder or in temp folder) that should to be executed. You was able to run that SQL script on SQL Server 2012, 2014, 2016...

Comment: @Anton From EXM version 3.3 it is distributed with databases (mdf and ldf files) and a script for updating database from previous versions.

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich In this case ExM script for creation database version 3.2 could be taken, and then scripts to update database to 3.5 version could be executed. 
P.S.: Of course, if 3.5 version is compatible with SQL 2014

Comment: @Anton yep, but there is a script for updating, for example, from 3.4 to 3.5 =). There are a lot of steps for installing databases by scripts from EXM 3.2. I have the MS SQL 2014 on my local machine and I just sucessfully attached a database from EXM 3.5 package.

Comment: hmm, I get errors attaching the databases (mdf/ldf) to SQL 2014:

The database 'Well_EXM_Sitecore_exm_master' cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'Well_EXM_Sitecore_exm_master'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)

Comment: I would raise this as a bug with Sitecore Support if that is the case. SQL 2016 is not officially support by 8.2 so it should not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a permission problem.

The databases released with EXM follow the [Sitecore compatibility table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164).

Please ensure that the database files are not in read-only mode, and that the user has access to them (you may, as a test, try granting Everyone full access).

As a test, I have just verified that the database files released with EXM 3.5 and 3.5.1 can be attached on SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000.8)

Comment: Yes I don’t know what happened with new exm download and new environment I didn’t have issues. Must have been a glitch

Answer (score 1):

I ended up restoring on SQL 2016, and create scripts from the db's to recreate them, which I then run on SQL 2014